# What's the best strategy to add WFE server to a SharePoint farm in virtualised environment?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My organization has a farm with 3 servers, 1 WFE, 1 APP and 1 DB. These are all VMs and we want to add a new WFE server to it.
What is the best strategy here? Should we start from scratch by installing OS, SharePoint etc. OR can we make a clone of the existing WFE.
Below are the services currently running in the WFE server.

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, clonning SharePoint Farm components is not supported by Microsoft.

But to save some time you can clone existing WFE, put it offline (**Disconnect-SPConfigurationDatabase**) to not interfere with current Farm, remove all Application Pools and Sites in IIS, remove SharePoint Logs, do SysPrep and then connect it to Farm with different name.

I recommend you do fresh install (OS,SP,Updates), but do not connect to Farm, then do SysPrep and save this image for future use (clonnable).

Also you should check [AutoSPInstaller](http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/)  project, it's awesome for Enterprise Farm setup, also good to prepare new nodes to join Farm.

Comment: AutoSPInstaller will help you a lot, but do not clone and remove components from an existing server. It took me hours to understand in a production farm that someone did that ! trust me, bad things happen !

Comment: @FrancoisVerbeeck out of curiosity, could you please share more about the problem you had because of this?

Comment: Some tricky services like the AppFabric Caching Service are deeply associated with Windows (machine name being a blatant example) and will need removal / reconfiguration to operate. In my case the clone server was the only one "trying to" run the DC. WFE "role" is simply associated with the fact the server do have the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" role activated on it but it can have a lot of other services running services underneath who where never thought to be tested in such a scenario. (I wouldn't be suprised to see server name references in some SharePoint databases)

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed article on this topic:

Add a Web or application server to the farm (SharePoint Server 2010)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261752%28v=office.14%29.aspx

In a nutshell, you do create it from scratch. There is no way to clone.

Comment: this is the way to go and not the recommended answer as of the time of writing this comment. Never clone a SP server.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a production environment.
To clone a WFE:
Put one of the WFEs offline/remove from any load balancing cluster.
Run the Disconnect-SPConfigurationDatabase command in PowerShell.
Disconnect the web site in IIS.
Delete SharePoint Logs.
Sysprep, clone and create a template from the clone.
Create a new server from the template and do the usual work getting it on your domain.
I used the psconfiggui.exe to join the server to the farm. Keep an eye on the Timer service and WWW service during the process, they will need to be restarted.
A good way to know if you have everything right is that during the psconfig process you will be asked for your farm passphrase.
Before bringing the server on line you have to add the desired applications to the server and make sure you have the correct certificates in the server certificates store in IIS.